# Site Map Node Issue Acumatica ERP

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

Loading the site returns the error: site map root node is null, the database is demo data stock

Answer (score 0):

You can run this SQL command against the database to check if the node exists:

```
SELECT * from sitemap where Title = 'Sitemap Root' and CompanyID > 0;
```

If it is not there the deployment is corrupted and you will need to re-install the website.
There's not enough information in the question to determine how it was deployed and which data set was used. For SalesDemo data it should be deployed from the wizard.

[image]